# Whats the meaning of the "build&run" button's arrow?

Tags: xcode, xcode6.4

Out of curiosity, when you open xCode and you want to run your app, you must to click "Play" button:

[image: xCode]

But when you hover this section, a little arrow appears (downright)

[image]

Does anybody know the meaning of that element, I thought it was a hidden menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click and hold on that button, a Menu will appear where you can switch the default action for this button.

You can see the other options here:

[image: Xcode run menu]

Note that you can modify these options by holding either shift (just build), alt (brings up the scheme selector for that scheme first) or ctrl (don't build, just run).